# iTextSharp - move Acrofield

Tags: c#, .net, itext, acrofields

I have a process that inserts a table of content into an existing Acroform, and I am able to track where I need to start that content.  However, I have existing Acrofields below that point that will need to be moved up or down, based on the height of the tables I insert.  With that, how can I change the position of an Acrofield?  Below is code that I can use to "get" the position...but now I also need to be able to "set" it.

....

```
            // Initialize Stamper ("output" is a MemoryStream object)
            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdf_rdr, output);

            // Get Reference to PDF Document Fields
            AcroFields fields = stamper.AcroFields;

            //call method to get the field's current position
            AcroFields.FieldPosition pos = GetFieldPosition(fields, "txt_footer");
```

// ** NEED TO EXPLICITLY SET A NEW POSITION FOR THE FIELD HERE

```
            //assuming a call to "RegenerateField" will be required
            fields.RegenerateField(txt_footer);
```

....

```
    //helper method for capturing the position of a field
    private static AcroFields.FieldPosition GetFieldPosition(AcroFields fields, string field_nm)
    {

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //get the left margin of the page, and the "top" location for starting positions
        //using the "regarding_line" field as a basis
        IList<AcroFields.FieldPosition> fieldPositions = fields.GetFieldPositions(field_nm);

        AcroFields.FieldPosition pos = fieldPositions[0];

        return pos;

    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First some info about fields and their representation on one or more pages. A PDF form can contain a number of fields. Fields have unique names in the sense that one specific field with one specific name has one and one value. Fields are defined using a *field dictionary*.

Each field can have zero, one or more representations in the document. These visual representations are called *widget annotations* and they are defined using an *annotation dictionary*.

Knowing this, your question needs to be rephrased: *how do I change the location of a specific widget annotation of a specific field?*

I've made a sample in Java named [ChangeFieldPosition](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/acroforms/ChangeFieldPosition) in answer to this question. It will be up to you to port it to C# (maybe you can post the C# answer here for further reference).

You already have the `AcroFields` instance:

```
 AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
```

What you need now is the `Item` instance for the specific field (in my example: for the field with name `"timezone2"`):

```
    Item item = form.getFieldItem("timezone2");
```

The position is a property of the widget annotation, so you need to ask the `item` for its widget. In the following line, I get the annotation dictionary for the first widget annotation (with index `0`):

```
    PdfDictionary widget = item.getWidget(0);
```

In most cases there will be only one widget annotation: each field has only one visual representation.

The position of the annotation is an array with four values: llx, lly, urx and ury. We can get this array like this:

```
    PdfArray rect = widget.getAsArray(PdfName.RECT);
```

In the following line I change the x-value of the upper-right corner (index `2` corresponds with urx):

```
    rect.set(2, new PdfNumber(rect.getAsNumber(2).floatValue() - 10f));
```

As a result the width of the field is shortened by 10pt.

Comment: C# version is the same, just need to pascal case the method calls, and floatValue is a property not a method.